# Why does DocumentBuilder Parse work OK in Eclipse, but not IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, android

I've been attempting to parse some XML via `DocumentBuilder.Parse`:

```
    try 
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works fine in Eclipse and return the `Document`.

However, run in IntelliJ IDEA the code hits `Document doc = builder.parse(in);` then skips directly past the entire try/catch and to a return `null` (or whatever code may be there) directly after the try/catch.

It throws no exceptions and provides no indication as to why it may simply fail!

Does anyone have any idea why this may happen? I'd really rather not go back to Eclipse

EDIT - Demonstration:

```
        try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in); //if we step through to here, this line executes then goes directly to "x" below
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null; //x
```

Also tried adding the following to catch errors, none of these were hit either:

```
            builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void error(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException
            {
                throw arg0;
            }

            @Override
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException
            {
                throw arg0;
            }

            @Override
            public void warning(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException
            {
                throw arg0;
            }
        });
```

EDIT 2: Imports

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
```

Comment: I would invalidates Idea caches (see quick action menu `Invalidates caches`), rebuild the project (`rebuild project`), redeploy and try again. Also a `Log.e("", "Exception", e)` in the `catch` block might help with diagnostic.

Comment: Hi RC - thanks for cleaning up the post, it was early morning ;) I've tried doing just that, but unfortunately it still jumps straight past the return. I've updated the question to demonstrate further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry, this comment got out of hand!)

What's your JRE? Also, can you paste your imports for this class? Fundamentally both IDEs run the bytecode on the same JVM so this sounds like a build-path issue to me (missing jar/alternate source). You should see an exception hit (though I'd subclass Throwable, not Exception in my catch).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.io.InputStream). Check your input source for a null source. IllegalArgumentException should be printed on a null, followed (in

**Looking at your code:**

```
  try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder(); //**<--What class is this?**
    Document doc = builder.parse(in); //if we step through to here, this line executes then goes directly to "x" below
    return doc;
} catch (Exception e) { //<-- Does not catch Error
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null; //x
```

**Try doing this:**

```
try
{
  //Your code to read the document
} 
catch (Throwable t)
{
  t.printStackTrace(); //Check your output
  //Set your breakpoint HERE
  throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage(), t); //Check the ExceptionHandler for the application.
}
```

I'm suggesting your factory isn't the factory you think it is **OR** that you're getting an Error class and something outside your code is swallowing that exception. There's a good chance your build path is set up differently.

Comment: Tried with both JDK 1.6 and 1.7 (two different dev machines), both exhibit the same issue. Adding imports to the original question

Comment: Does this work if you swap out the entity in question to a test file that you know works?

Comment: For some reason simply commenting out my code, pasting in your version of the try/catch and popping my code back in the try has "solved" the issue (i.e. the code is now executing correctly). However, nothing was ever caught within the catch

Comment: Sounds like it was a "clean" build to me. If it executes correctly you wouldn't see the exception right?

Comment: Seems so - but you'd think having cleaned and rebuilt (and even completely re-constructed the project on a seperate machine!) would have solved that. Very odd indeed!